# CORS problem with NodeJS Express and ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I have some CORS problem with NodeJS Express and ReactJS. Please help me.

Now, I have both frontend(`http://locahost:3000`) and backend(`http://locahost:4000`) using different `PORT`.
The frontend is using 3000 port with ReactJS and the Backend is using 4000 port with NodeJS Express.

**Frontend API call source code**

```
axios.get("/tube/latestted",
    {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Backend CORS setting source code

```
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

  next();
});
```

or

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

But it still has the same problem as the blow error message, even though I set up CORS setup.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/tube/latestted' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: To see why it is being denied, you need to look at the EXACT network request being sent by the browser and see exactly what is coming back from the server and see what is being put in the debug log in the browser.  In the Chrome browser, open the Network tab in the debugger, then make this request and look at exactly what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Content-Type: application/json` on your client-side request makes your cross origin request into a request that needs pre-flight and the client will send an OPTIONS request to your that route on your server essentially asking your server if it's permissible to make a cross origin call to that route.  For that type of request to succeed in a browser, you need a handler for the OPTIONS verb that returns a 200 status like this:

```
app.options("/tube/latestted", (req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');        
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

But, a simpler solution is likely to just remove the custom Content-Type header from your client request.  The `Content-Type` header specifies the type of content you are SENDING with the request, not the type of content you are expecting back.  Since you are sending no data with the GET request, you do not need that header and it is that header that is making your Ajax call go from a [Simple Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests) to a [Pre-Flighted Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) which requires the OPTIONS preflight.

The only  `Content-Type` header values that are allowed without preflight are:

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
text/plain
```

You will notice that `application/json` is not listed so using that content-type is forcing the browser to do pre-flight which your server is not handling.

So, **the first thing to try** is to change the client request to this:

```
axios.get("/tube/latestted")
  .then(response => {
     console.log(response);
  }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
  });
```

If that doesn't work, then you should diagnose further by looking at the Chrome debugger Network tab in the browser and see exactly what is happening when the browser runs that Ajax call.  Chances are you will see an OPTIONS request that comes back as a 404 or some other non-200 status.  If that's the case, then you need to add a specific OPTIONS handler in your server that returns a 200 status for that route.  You have middleware that will set the CORS headers, but you call `next()` in that route so since there is no other matching OPTIONS route handler, it will presumably fall through to a 404 handler and thus the browser thinks the OPTIONS request has failed.

Comment: @박현근 - Which option did you use to fix it?

Comment: I am using the second option.