# serverless express app for aws: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, express, aws-api-gateway, serverless

I have created a serverless express app and deploy it to aws.
When I tried to access the endpoint from my front end application.
I got the following error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Here is my express app:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
next();
```

});

my route:

```
app.get('/test', async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    var params = {};
    let bucketList = BluebirdPromise.promisify(s3.listBuckets.bind(s3));
    let data = await bucketList(params);
    console.log(data);
    res.send({data: data});
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send('error on the bucketList');
}
```

})

and the serverless.yml:

```
service: sample-app
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-2
  memorySize: 128
functions:
 app:
  handler: app.handler
  events: 
    - http: 
      path: /
      method: ANY
      cors: true
    - http: 
      path: /{proxy+}
      method: ANY
      cors: true
```

I don't know how to solve that problem.
Does someone have an idea?

EDIT:

client side get request:

```
let resp = await axios.get(`${backendUrl}/start-upload`,
        {
            params: {
            fileName: selectedFile.name,
            fileType: selectedFile.type
          }
        });
```

Comment: Please show the client-side code making the request so we can see exactly what's in it.  If you're setting a content-type on the GET request to `application/json`, then you can fix it just like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65153590/cors-problem-with-nodejs-express-and-reactjs/65153663#65153663).

Comment: hi,
i dont have any content-type in my GET request. Please see the edit

Comment: Then, you need to look in the Network tab of the Chrome debugger and watch the exact exchange between your client request and the server to see what the browser is doing and thus why the CORs request is being rejected.  If that doesn't make it clear to you what is happening, then add the info from that Network tab to your question so we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

As you have placed `cors` correctly, Seems like your url is incorrect.

Your `${backendUrl}` must be `https://{api-gateway-url}/{env-name}/start-upload`

Comment: yes the url is correct.... i just dont know where this error comes from...

Comment: Is your API is publishing the response? Check in network tools or directly hitting the url from postman. Chrome shows `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` even when main service is behind an api-gateway and responses are masked by api-gateway responses.