# API calls blocked by CORS even with Access-Control-Allow-Origin : * present in headers

Tags: express, nginx, cors, nginx-reverse-proxy

API calls from react site keep getting blocked by CORS even tho both the react app and the api are served with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *` header along with allowed methods `'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS'` and cors credentials are allowed as well

This is the exact error :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cbiapi.dailycode.tk/parse/classes/_Installation' from origin 'https://backoffice.dailycode.tk' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**website URL :** https://backoffice.dailycode.tk/login
**API url :** https://cbiapi.dailycode.tk/parse

I don't understand why my api calls are still blocked, I tried CORS everywhere plugin and other plugins of the kind but calls are still being blocked

Comment: Please show the actual client code that is sending the request.  Certain content-types and custom headers require additional steps to permit a CORS request.  You will also typically learn a lot by looking at the Network tab of the Chrome debugger in the browser when sending one of these requests as it will show exactly what is being sent and returned from the server.  For example, it will show you if your CORS request has been classified as a request that requires pre-flight in which case you would have to implement a server-side handler for an OPTIONS request.

Comment: See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65153590/cors-problem-with-nodejs-express-and-reactjs/65153663#65153663) for a discussion of simple requests and pre-flighted requests.

Comment: Now I see in the details of your error message that your request is trigger a pre-flight check so you probably don't have a server-side handler for that pre-flight request.

Comment: See you found the problem without me sharing client code :p
Not that I didn't wanna share the crient code ,but the client uses Parse Server SDK so the requests are made from that library i never make any requests my self

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your client request (based on what's in the request) has triggered a cross origin pre-flight check.  That means the browser will send your client an OPTIONS request (to the same URL of the request) and it expects to get back a 2xx status in order to allow the CORS request.

Any number of things can trigger a pre-flight request.  These include most custom headers, and many content-types other than just a couple.

You can see more in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65153590/cors-problem-with-nodejs-express-and-reactjs/65153663#65153663) and you can read about it on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests).

Your API server will need to handle an OPTIONS request.  You don't show any of the relevant API server code, but if the URL is `https://cbiapi.dailycode.tk/parse` and the server environment was Express, you would need something like this in your API server:

```
app.options("/parse", cors(), (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(204);
});
```

This can be adjusted to only allow some origins if you want it partially locked down.  This example would allow all origins to do cross origin access from a browser.

Comment: This solved my problem , my api doesn't use OPTIONS and adding this solved my problem ,Thank you